# onItemSelected method help - loading an Intent

Tags: android

I have tried Googling but couldn't get an answer specific to my problem.

I am trying to launch an activity when a item is clicked. The code is below:

```
public class ListOfCircuits extends Activity
{
String[] raceTrackList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_of_circuits);

    raceTrackList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tracklist_array);

    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.circuitListSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, raceTrackList);

    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "You have selected: " + raceTrackList[index],
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String intentString;

            String circuitChosen = raceTrackList[index].toString();
            intentString = ("net.learn2develop." + circuitChosen);

            startActivity(new Intent(intentString));
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

However at the moment it loads straight into the activity at the top of the list (TopGear). How do you get around this so that a user can see the list and select it i.e. not start an intent immediately - use an if statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the method is called the first time the `Activity` loads. There *should* be a better way to handle this but you could simply set a `boolean` flag

```
public class ListOfCircuits extends Activity
{
    String[] raceTrackList;
    boolean go = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
```

then set it to true the first time it is called and check it there

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        if (go)
        {
             // your code
            intentString = ("net.learn2develop." + circuitChosen);
            startActivity(new Intent(intentString));
        }
        else
        {    go = true;    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that it doesn't work perfectly as it loads with a list and at the top where TopGear is if you select it it doesn't load the intent. I have worked around this by adding a "Choose from below:" option at the top and now when I click TopGear it works fine. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to and an if statement so the "Choose from below:" Intent doesn't fire.

Comment: I don't understand that last comment. You might need to post the new code. Just edit your post, without changing the original code, and add it there and I will try to look.

Comment: Sorry - saw this comment after I posted my "Answer". If you can think of a better solution please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: That should work but see my comment on your answer. Another way would be to have a `Button` and forget the flag and only start the intent when the button is clicked. But that may not be an option for you, I don't know

Comment: I did have a button that then loaded the Intent but the idea of using a selector like this is that it looks better (IMO) than a load of buttons to create a (what could be) a long list) so I thought I'd give it a go. Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: No problem, and your way should work. I would just use the position of the item as I stated because it will be safer in case you, say, decide to change the text of that first element. Unfortunately, there still is no native way around this without creating your own adapter class, extend spinner, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my answer was:

Add the Boolean as codeMagic suggested and amend my array to:

```
<string-array name="tracklist_array">
    <item>Choose from below:</item>
    <item>TopGear</item>
    <item>Snetterton</item>
    <item>Silverstone</item>
    <item>Donnington</item>
</string-array>
```

From

```
<string-array name="tracklist_array">
    <item>TopGear</item>
    <item>Snetterton</item>
    <item>Silverstone</item>
    <item>Donnington</item>
</string-array>
```

And the final code is for Java - see below.
Thanks again.

Comment: It would be better to check the `index` instead of checking what the word contains. `if (index == 0){//wrong choice code`

Answer (score 0):

CodeMagic think I have it working like a boss now:

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            if(go)
            {
                int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                if(index == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Please select a race crcuit.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You have selected: " + raceTrackList[index],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    String intentString;

                    String circuitChosen = raceTrackList[index].toString();
                    intentString = ("net.learn2develop." + circuitChosen);

                    startActivity(new Intent(intentString));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                go = true;
            }
        }
```

I only load Intents that I want (race circuits) and if a user selects "Choose from below:" only one relevant Toast gets displayed.

Thanks.